# Is it equal to reported speech case?

Tags: past-tense, future-tense, past-simple, reported-speech

Reported speech case:

> He said I would do it

Direct speech:

> He said, "I will do it."

My sentence:

> He thought that he **WILL / WOULD** do it tomorrow

Question:

In my sentence should I use 'would' verb (because the case is equal to reported speech)?

**or**

I should leave 'will' verb because the case is completely different to reported speech case

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

> He thought he **would**
>   He thought he **will**

it depends on what you want to say and mood to be.

Comment: He thought he will do it. ? Buzzer.

Comment: "Will" is just about possible, if you are referring to a past opinion of present events, but "would" is still more natural. I might use "will" in special cases where past and present are combined, such as "He said that he will be there, but now he's not so sure" but not otherwise. Using "would" is probably the best rule for a learner.

Answer (score 0):

In the reported speech, you are describing, the speech from your point of view.  Since the person who is going to "do it" is "him" you do need to say

> He said (that) he ...

After that there is possibility of backshifting.  If you are certain that the action is still in the future you probably would not backshift:

> The dog needs to go for a walk who can do that?
>
> John said that he will do it.

If you want to indicate that you don't know if action is still in the future, you can use would:

> Has anyone walked the dog yet?
>
> John said that he would do it.